# Why \@ifnextchar doesn't work correctly within of a unicodechar definition?

Tags: unicode, unicode-math

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\makeatletter
    \newunicodechar{∑}{\@ifnextchar_{\sum}{\@ifnextchar^{\sum}{\Sigma}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    Incorrect ({\bf why?}):
    \[
        ∑_1^{100} \qquad
        ∑_{100}^1 \qquad
        ∑ 
    \]

    Correct: 
    \makeatletter
    \[
        \@ifnextchar_{\sum}{\@ifnextchar^{\sum}{\Sigma}}_1^{100} \qquad
        \@ifnextchar_{\sum}{\@ifnextchar^{\sum}{\Sigma}}^{100}_1 \qquad
        \@ifnextchar_{\sum}{\@ifnextchar^{\sum}{\Sigma}}
    \]
    \makeatother

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]
When I use a unicode symbol "∑", the output symbol is invisible, however, when I write explicitly the code of the definition of the unicode symbol "∑", the output is correctly.

**Why? Any solution?**

Comment: It works when you add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. Indeed you get the warning `This package won't work without loading 'inputenc' or 'inputenx' with the 'utf8' option`.

Comment: Thanks, but try adding the breqn package.

Comment: `breqn` changes the category code of `_` and `^` to be 12, but only at begin document. So the `_` and `^` specified in the definition in the preamble can't be found (because they have category code 8 and 7 respectively).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `newunicodechar` package requires to load

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

(also `inputenx` is allowed). It doesn't load it by default for various reasons. Indeed

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\makeatletter
\newunicodechar{∑}{\@ifnextchar_{\sum}{\@ifnextchar^{\sum}{\Sigma}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
∑_1^{100} \qquad
∑^{100}_1 \qquad
∑
\]

\end{document}
```

will work as expected.

If you also load `breqn` you have to take care of the fact that it changes the category code of `_` and `^`, but only at begin document. So that definition won't work, because the macros look for `_` and `^` with category code 8 and 7 respectively, and can't find them.

Some tricks are necessary to cope with this. Here's one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{breqn}

\makeatletter
\begingroup\lccode`?=`_ \lccode`!=`^
\def\x{\newunicodechar{∑}}
\lowercase{\expandafter\endgroup
   \x{\@ifnextchar?{\sum}{\@ifnextchar!{\sum}{\Sigma}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
∑_1^{100} \qquad
∑^{100}_1 \qquad
∑
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

But this is wrong. If you want an upper case sigma, then input U+03A3 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER SIGMA, not U+2211 N-ARY SUMMATION.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{breqn}

\newunicodechar{∑}{\sum}
\newunicodechar{Σ}{\ensuremath{\Sigma}}

\begin{document}
\[
∑_1^{100} \qquad
∑^{100}_1 \qquad
Σ
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it a good idea to do this? \newunicodechar{∑}{\@ifnextchar\@@subscript@other{\sum}{\@ifnextchar\@@superscript@other{\sum}{\Sigma}}}.  \@@subscript@other and \@@superscript@other are used in breqn package.

Comment: @David It depends on how `\@@subscript@other` is defined. Possibly so. But I can't recommend using U+2211 for two distinct roles.